# you tube integration with authentication in android app

Tags: android

In my android application i would like to integrate you tube.Could anyone please let me know where i can get in details use of gdata api for this.

Please let me know your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. You should probably not use the GData API for this, but the newer [google-api-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) ([Justification](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/wiki/MigratingToGoogleApiJavaClient#Why_you_will_want_to_migrate)).
2. There are [a few integration points](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/articles/youtube_mobileresources.html#security) for the integration of the authentication (AuthSub, OAuth and ClientLogin). The recommended approach is to use the AccountManager as a wrapper. [Sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/AndroidAccountManager).
3. Include the resulting authentication token in calls with the [YouTube Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html).